# The driver executable does not exist - Failure in Before Hook

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

This is a question that has been asked a few times before but with previous topics, the suggestions didn't

work for me so I thought it would be noteworthy to put out my particular scenario.

So when I run my file, I get the following error messages :

```
**The driver executable does not exist: C**  


**Failure in before hook:LoginSteps.setup()**
```

And this particular code is probably the issue :

```
**@Before() 
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")).toRealPath() + "\\src\test\\java\\CucumberFramework\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");        
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();**
```

Not sure what the problem is. ChromeDriver is up to date and also my Chrome Browser, and everything seems to be pointing to the right place.

**- Windows 10**

Comment: It seems like there is no exe file on your path of computer

Comment: yeah that's why I'm confused because I actually have chromedriver.exe installed at that particular path. Wish I could post pics in here.

Comment: Are you using Macbook or windows?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10